# Meta Query for Custom Post Type not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use the WordPress REST API for custom posts and useing parameters to filter. I created the parameters `course_no`, `course_cycles` and `course_type`. Those are meta fields of the course posts.

I'm using the `rest_course_query` filter hook for that. That's the code:

```
// Add custom field filters for REST API
function chld_thm_post_meta_request_params( $args, $request ) {

    $hasFilterCourseNo = false;
    $hasFilterCourseCycles = false;
    $hasFilterCourseType = false;

    // meta query for course number
    if ($request['course_no'] != null) {
        $hasFilterCourseNo = true;
        $courseNoMetaQuery = array(
            'key'     => 'course_no',
            'value'   => $request['course_no'],
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    // meta query for course cycles
    if ($request['course_cycles'] != null) {
        $hasFilterCourseCycles = true;
        $courseCycleMetaQuery = array(
            'relation' => 'OR'
        );
        foreach (explode(",", $request['course_cycles']) as $course_cycle) {
            $currentCycle = array(
                'key' => 'course_cycles',
                'value' => serialize($course_cycle),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
            array_push($courseCycleMetaQuery, $currentCycle);
        }
    }

    // meta query for course type
    if ($request['course_type'] != null) {
        $hasFilterCourseType = true;
        $courseTypeMetaQuery = array(
            'key'     => 'course_type',
            'value'   => $request['course_type'],
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    $meta_query_args = array(
        'relation' => 'AND'
    );

    if ($hasFilterCourseNo == true) {
        array_push( $meta_query_args, $courseNoMetaQuery);
    }
    if ($hasFilterCourseCycles == true) {
        array_push( $meta_query_args, $courseCycleMetaQuery);
    }
    if ($hasFilterCourseType == true) {
        array_push( $meta_query_args, $courseTypeMetaQuery);
    }

    $meta_query = array(
        'meta_query' => $meta_query_args
    );

    $args = $args + $meta_query; // TODO looks like meta_query is not working here

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_course_query', 'chld_thm_post_meta_request_params', 99, 2 );
```

Using this I can use the following request: `wp-json/wp/v2/course?search=&per_page=100&course_type=non_subsidized`

Unfortunately it's not filtering the `course_type` for `non_subsidized` here.

This creates a completely fine WP Query using `meta_query`.

```
  'meta_query' => 
    array (size=2)
      'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'key' => string 'course_type' (length=11)
          'value' => string 'non_subsidized' (length=14)
          'compare' => string '=' (length=1)
```

But for some reason the WordPress REST API doesn't acknowledge the `meta_query` parameter.

Using `meta_key` and `meta_value` instead of `meta_query` is working fine. But I can't combine different parameters using `meta_key` and `meta_value`, so I have to use `meta_query`.

Does anybody know, why this is not working in WordPress 5.7 and 5.8?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I added an additional `meta_query` for ordering the posts using `pre_get_posts`.

The `meta_query` was overwritten there. Instead of overwriting it, I merged the existing `meta_query` and now it's working.

```
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
$meta_query_order = array(
    'order_course_date' => array(
        'key' => 'course_date_start',
        'value' => date("Ymdhi"),
        'compare' => '<='
    )
);
if (is_array($meta_query)) {
    $meta_query_new = array_merge($meta_query, $meta_query_order);
} else {
    $meta_query_new = $meta_query_order;
}

$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_new);
$query->set('orderby', 'order_course_date');
$query->set('order', 'ASC');
```